# javascript equivalent of file_get_contents

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use below code in php to send a POST data,What is the javascript equivalent of this ?

```
 $post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$photo[id]."/tags/".$m."/?access_token=".$access_token."&x=20&y=20&method=POST"; 
 $response = file_get_contents($post_url);
```

Comment: Well you can't (in general) do that from a web browser. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Comment: [`AJAX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes you can, notice he is getting the contents of a url.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I see now he's using the web-enabled version of `file_get_contents`. Still, it's not usually possible unless the site is on the same domain.

Comment: Note: Sticking a `&method=POST` to a query string does not magically turn your GET request into a POST request. This is accomplished via [context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) (in PHP, not in JS).

Comment: All i need is to send a post data to graph.facebook.com , i think ajax is possible

Comment: You should use this: [FB.api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/)